Clerk Auth in expo react native error - missing captcha token
I Have used clerk before for authentication. But the error I am getting today is weird. Has anyone bumped into it?
"status": 400,
"clerkError": true,
"errors": [
    {
      "code": "captcha_missing_token",
      "message": "Missing CAPTCHA token",
      "longMessage": "Missing CAPTCHA token",
      "meta": {}
    }
  ]
}

I have followed the SignUp steps to the tee but I run into this error

Where are you trying this? can you please elaborate

I am using expo and react native. @rizzling provided an answer though

I found this on Github, hope it helps.
Based on the error you're encountering with Expo and Clerk authentication, this is a known issue with CAPTCHA in non-browser environments like Expo/React Native. The "Missing CAPTCHA token" error occurs because Clerk's bot protection feature is not supported in mobile environments. To resolve this, you'll need to disable bot protection in your Clerk Dashboard. Go to User & Authentication > Attack Protection and turn off the Bot sign-up protection. This should resolve the CAPTCHA token error and allow authentication to work properly in your Expo application.
